# how do call specific css for specific browser using jquery

Tags: jquery

how do call specific css for specific browser using jquery

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation on coding browser specific for jQuery.](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser)

I'm not sure what you mean by specific css, but here's an example getting the browser and then using CSS selectors to show those classes.

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
  $('.myspecificcssclass').show();
}
```

Generally, you shoudn't need to do this, but...

Comment: "Deprecated in jQuery 1.3", meaning it might be dropped from a future release.  A better solution is to use the jQuery.support properties, like boxModel and cssFloat.  It'll give you better control.
http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for: [CSS Browser detection using jQuery](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx)

```
<code>
#myInput{background:black;} .browserSafari
#myInput{background:black; position:relative; top:2px;} 
</code>

//example calls specific css for Safari:
```

Answer (score 0):

its not longer done by browser sniffing in jQuery 1.3+, 
but by support it has for several things like right 
W3C box model support, ect.

[see - jQuery.support](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support) for further reading on the subject in the API.