# how do call different css for corresponding browsers like using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is already asked [how do call specific css for specific browser using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848227/how-do-call-specific-css-for-specific-browser-using-jquery)

I want to use one css file for safari and other for Mozilla and other for IE

Comment: What about Webkit? What about Opera? What about lesser known browsers? In 99%+ of cases, it is better to write one standards compliant stylesheet and then use Conditional Comments to include IE6 and IE7 specific stylesheets to override selected parts of the main stylesheet to work around bugs in those particular browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do this on server-side (or even better, not at all). But if you wan't to do this client side you need something like this.

```
var writeStyleSheet = function(url){
    var linkTag = document.createElement('link');
    linkTag.type = 'text/css';
    linkTag.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkTag.href = url;
    linkTag.media = 'screen';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(linkTag);
}
if(jQuery.brwoser.msie){
    writeStyleSheet('ie.css');
}
else if(jQuery.browser.safari){
    writeStyleSheet('safari.css');
}
else if(jQuery.browser.mozilla){
    writeStyleSheet('mozalla.css');
}
```

Note however that jQuery.browser is deprecated in 1.3. You should create a stylesheet that works on all browsers. Possibly add some conditional comments for IE specific hacks:

```
 <!--[if IE]>
  <link type='text/css' href='ieHacks.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sniff the browser and then create a `link` element and append it to the `head` tag.

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie)
    $('head').append('<link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
... // and so on.
```

EDIT: Reference for [jQuery.browser](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can detect browser using $.browser object.

to get required stylesheet I got following from this [blog entry](http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/02/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery.aspx)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" 
         type="text/css" />');
    });
});
```

here is another nice post by [Kelvin Luck](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2006/05/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery/) that describes replacing and applying styles dynamically using jquery.